# 3.3V controlled with 1.6V

Tags: transistors

I have 0V/1.6V input signal comming to my device and I have to use it as  'Enable' signal to one of the ICs, which accepts 0V/3.3V levels.

To build such a level shifter generally I know I should connect input to transistor base, +3.3V to collector and 'Enable' to emitter.

Additional requirements are:
1) I have to take minimum current from the source as possible -> base resistor must be big enough.
2) When there is 0V on the input, in reality there will be some small signal due to capacitance -> base resistor can't be too big to discharge it.

Could you please help me with it? I don't have practical knowledge, I don't know how to build it.

Comment: Is the sense of the ENABLE signal high or low?

Comment: @EMFields 0V - disabled, 3.3V - enabled

Comment: Also, did you check the exact ENABLE signal levels from your device datasheet? Some regulators, for example, happily take high levels as low as 1V on their enable pins. If you're lucky, you won't actually need anything.

Comment: The ENABLE signal can't come from the emitter since if it does the transistor will be used as a common-emitter amplifier and the emitter voltage will be your input signal minus the about 0.7 volt drop across the base-to-emitter junction .

Comment: How much current is available from the 1.6 volt source?

Comment: @dim yes, I've checked it - Vih=2V

Comment: @EMFields I'm not sure how much current is available. It is LVDS transmission line, I think 20-30mA is used for transmission.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non inverting level shifter that may do what you want;

[image: level shifter]

Here is a simulation result;

[image]

Depending on speeds and current limits, you can adjust the resistor values to get the balance you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a diode and a pull-up resistor to 3.3 volts it will probably work. With 1.6 volts being outputted to the cathode of the diode, the anode will be at about 2.2 to 2.3 volts with a 1 to 10 kohm pull up to 3V3.

It's basically a 0.6 to 0.7 volt level shifter and potentially the down side is that with 0V being outputted, after the diode this might be as high as 0.7 volts BUT if this is within the voltage range for a logic 0 for your input device then it should be OK.

You never mentioned how fast this needs to operate so, if it needs to run faster than a few tens of MHz you may get other problems.

Comment: It will be very slow operation, every few minutes.
Thanks for this answer, I will consider it, but I would like to know 'transistor' solution.

Comment: Emitter to 0V and input (1.6 volt signal) to base via 10k resistor. Collector to 3v3 via 10k resistor and collector also feeds output to 3V3 stage. There will be a signal inversion with this method and that is why I recommended the diode method.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjiCRa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Results:
[image: Results]

Base current here would be approximately (1.6-0.9)/5600 ~= 0.16 mA = 160 uA

Answer (score -1):

If you want the output to go high when VIN goes high, connect the comparator's inverting input to the voltage divider's output.

If you want the output to go low when VIN goes high, connect the comparator's non-inverting input to the voltage divider's output; see the green boxes, below.

I've shown the LT1716 as the comparator because of convenience, but almost any comparator will work. Some have open-collector outputs, though, so for them a pullup needs to be added between the output and the proper supply rail.

[image]